# Simplify function returning module

Tags: ocaml

This function should be able to simplify, removing the unnecessary `let module T = ...`. But how?! I keep getting syntax errors. Tips?

```
let make_module dice_results : (module Tellstory.T) =
  let dice_calls = ref 0 in (* nr of times dice has been called *)
  let module T = Tellstory.Make(struct
    let dice n = 
      let result = List.nth dice_results (!dice_calls) in
      dice_calls := !dice_calls + 1;
      result
  end) in
  (module T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't check your module, but this is an example for inspiration:

```
let make_module () : (module Unit) =
  (module Comparable.Make (struct type t = int with compare, sexp end))
```

Looks like that the following, should work:

```
let make_module dice_results : (module Tellstory.T) =
  let dice_calls = ref 0 in (* nr of times dice has been called *)
  (module Tellstory.Make(struct
    let dice n = 
      let result = List.nth dice_results (!dice_calls) in
      dice_calls := !dice_calls + 1;
      result
  end))
```

Comment: Right you are, but syntastic in Vim doesn't agree. Wonder why... :P